# Layer on which ball belongs in tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

What is the most computationally efficient way to find the layer on which a ball (i) belongs when arranged in a tetrahedron or 3 dimensional triangle with a triangular base. The ball on the top layer is numbered one. The balls on the second layer are numbered 2 - 4. The third layer 5-10 and so on.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Are you talking about a set of spheres stacked in a close-packed (tetrahedral) arrangement? If so the question is very confusingly worded. Should "fifth layer" be "third layer"? Should "4-10" be "5-10"?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000292 -- highlight of the page is this sentence: *a(n) is the number of gifts received from the lyricist's true love up to and including day n in the song "The Twelve Days of Christmas".*

Comment: @GeoffOxberry no. I am trying to make a way of indexing the i'th combination of all combinations of something without making a list of all combinations. If i am able to find x,y,z (on a tetrahedron) of an index from 1 - max balls(each ball representing a combo) than I can construct the combination.

Answer (score 1):

Rootfinding is probably the most computationally efficient way to find the layer in which a ball $i$ resides in a close-packed tetrahedral arrangement. Assume the balls are labeled consecutively such that balls increase as the layer number increases, so that layer 1 corresponding to the topmost ball (i.e., ball 1), layer 2 is beneath layer 1 (balls 2-4), layer 3 is beneath layer 2 (balls 5-10), and so on.

Since the number of objects in an $n$-layer tetrahedron is $T_{n} = n(n+1)(n+2)/6$, if $m$ satisfies $T_{n-1} < m \leq T_{n}$, ball $m$ is in layer $n$, with the convention that $T_{0} = 0$. This observation suggests the following procedure: solve $n(n+1)(n+2)/6 = m$ for $n$. Then $\lceil{n}\rceil$ (the ceiling of $n$) will be the layer number containing ball $m$.

In certain applications, you might instead want to store a sequence of tetrahedral numbers (according to the formula above) and then perform a table lookup instead of using rootfinding.